# How to find if objects of an array are equals

Tags: java, equals

the method equals is overriden but findEquals doesn't print "duplicate" even when i enter for every Egnine's new object same variables.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    EngineStorage that = (EngineStorage) o;
    return Arrays.equals(engines, that.engines) && scanner.equals(that.scanner);
}

public void fillArray(Engine[] engines) {

    for (int i = 0; i < engines.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter model");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter volume");
        double vol = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine();
        engines[i] = new Engine(name, vol);
    }
}

public void findEquals(Engine [] engines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < engines.length - 1; i++) {
        if (engines[i].equals(engines[i + 1])) {
            System.out.println("duplikat");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to override `equals` in `EngineStorage` class.

You should also override it in `Engine` class, so that `Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)` will use your implementation.

Besides, your `findEquals` method explicitly calls `equals` on `Engine` instances, which is another reason to override `equals` in that class.